# How to calculate the distance between cable supports, considering the weight and other factors?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

I am designing a cable infrastructure and have come across the question of calculating the optimal distance between supports for cables. What formula can be used to determine this distance, taking into account the cable weight, tightening torque, and other important parameters? Are there standard methods widely used in the industry, or recommended formulas for such calculations? I would appreciate any useful information or recommendations in this regard. Thank you!

Comment: What have you found so far? Lots of info about this exists.

Comment: So far I have only found already specified distances between cable supports in installation standards (for ex. https://etechcomponents.com/calculating-the-correct-cable-cleat-spacing/). I'm interested in how to calculate the distance between supports for a group of cables installated along a vertical wall

Comment: You need to figure out allowable cable geometry.  You may want it to be taught or allow some slack so it can deform between mounting points to better bear load.  Cable is typically modeled as being able to bear a force along its length, but only in tension.  It can be thought of as a truss member of those constraints that will readily split into multiple members.

Comment: I think in my case I need to calculate the distance between the cable supports so that they sag under their own weight by a given amount. Is there any formula for this?